# How to migrate MS access database to Oracle?

Tags: ms-access, oracle10g, ms-access-2003, database-migration

I am using SQL developer, but while capturing Models step executes, it gives me following error

oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors1(XMLError.java:323)

Can anyone either tell me how to fix this issue or help in with an alternate way to migrate the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used same tool but removed selected option of not copying the constraints and copy only tables structures and data. This fixed the issue.